# AUCTeX doesn't run bibtex even though .emacs file is set up appropriately

Tags: auctex, bibtex

I created a simple BibTeX file as well as a simple LaTeX file that references said BibTeX file. However, when I printed out the LaTex file in pdf format by running `C-c C-a` (which, [according to the AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#One-Command-for-LaTeX_002c-helpers_002c-viewers_002c-and-printing), runs BibTeX, amongst other things),the bibliography section didn't appear and the citations were broken.

Trying to debug the problem, I replaced the single `C-c C-a` command by a sequence of `C-c C-c` commands (since, according to the AUCTeX manual section linked to above, `C-c C-a` is an abbreviation for such a sequence), and noticed that the bibtex command was not executed.

A similar question [was posted in the past](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13426/auctex-doesnt-run-bibtex), to which the solution was to add a couple lines to the initialization file, but these lines are already in my initialization file.

**Bibliography.bib**

```
@book{WEN08,
    Author = {Jochen Wengenroth},
    Date-Added = {2017-05-08 08:16:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-05-08 08:19:24 +0000},
    Publisher = {de Gruyter},
    Title = {Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie},
    Year = {2008}}
```

**MyDoc.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{WEN08}. 

\bibliography{Bibliography}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

**.emacs includes the following lines:**

```
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

**Resulting pdf file**
[image: Resulting pdf file with a blank bibliography and a broken citation]

---

AUCTeX 11.90.0
Emacs 25.1.1
TeX Live 2016, v. 3.14159265
macOS Sierra, v. 10.12.4

Comment: Did you restart Emacs after setting the init file?

Comment: @giordano: The init file had had these lines to begin with.

Comment: I see.  Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Crosspost: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368708/31416

Comment: @giordano: If you read the comments section in the crosspost you'll see that egreg was able to reproduce the issue, so it's not just me.

Comment: What does `C-h v` `LaTeX-bibliography-list` `RET` return in `MyDoc.tex` buffer?

Comment: @giordano: 'Its value is nil'

Comment: Then parsing isn't working correctly for you (don't know why).  It should be `(("Bibliography"))` and it's so for me.  Try issuing `C-c C-n` in `MyDoc.tex` buffer and then check again the value of the variable.

Comment: @giordano: Sorry for the late reply. I closed Emacs and reopened it, and then issued `C-c C-n`, as per your suggestion. Then I issued `C-c C-a`, and the resulting pdf file had the bibliography section as well as the citation. So all is well. Thank you! What does `C-c C-n` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, the file wasn't actually parsed, so AUCTeX didn't know about the bibliography file.  This shouldn't usually happen if you set [`TeX-parse-self`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dparse_002dself) and [`TeX-auto-save`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dauto_002dsave) to `t`, but you can easily trigger parsing with <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> ([`TeX-normal-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dnormal_002dmode)).